# robot does not stops when key is released from keyboard with teleop_twist_keyboard

Tags: ros, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I am navigating a P3AT with teleop_twist_keyboard.py node, it works fine but the problem is that as soon the key is pressed robot starts moving even if i release the key and i have to stop it by pressing the key again.

how can i stop the robot immediately after releasing the key from keyboard??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202771/robot-does-not-stops-when-key-is-released-from-keyboard-with-teleop_twist_keyboard./) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just how [teleop_twist_keyboard.py](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard/blob/master/teleop_twist_keyboard.py) is currently written; It's convenient since the robot keeps moving in the same direction and/or orientation unless different command is sent.

Depending on how serious your usecase is, you could write a patch to maybe send pull request to [teleop_twist_keyboard repository](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard); e.g. a code that adds an option to stop the robot per each command. Shouldn't be any difficult.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think teleop_twist_keyboard.py publishes only when the key is pressed, so it seems P3AT controller holding last input and keep moving, usually robot controller check input every seconds and if there are no input, it stops motion (in that case you have to push key continuously)

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manuelmelvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30611/manuelmelvin/) on 2018-07-10**:
I am also facing same issue with my Pioneer p3dx gazebo simulation. If we are sending velocity command  " rostopic pub -1 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.2, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.10]'
" after 3 second the robot should stop moving, But it is moving continuously.please help